# Create Printing View for 3D Printing

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-printing

I do not really know how to start off, I am just introducing myself to Blender because of a personal project.
I wanted to combine the 3D Printing with Blender. I am not actually trying to write a printing software from scratch but I am trying my best to work with what's out there since there is much good printing software.
My problem is now that for this purpose I of Course also need to create a "Printing View" with a Printing Bed where the 3D Models will be placed on, but I really do not know how to achieve this Printing View in Blender. And I also do not know how to actually integrate the Printing bed, which I also have to model in Blender.

I am really thankful for every little help or idea.

Comment: You mean you want a "floor" inside blender that represents the build plate of your 3d printer? If so, check out this video - The real content starts at 2:30 discussing scale, if you don't need that, skip to 5:40 for the setup. Build "floor" starts at 6:30. - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqDnLg3o9WE He also discusses view windows.

Comment: Yes exactly!!! I will have a look, thank you very much!